# Overriding macros using compiler options

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I need to be override certain macro definition by my header file. And I am not allowed to change source code. And I have to use gcc, but if anyone is aware of something similar on any other compiler then also it will help.

Here is what I exactly need:

Lets say I have code base with lot of .c files. These .c files include .h files. After all the .h files have been included for each file I want the compiler to behave as if I have another `extra.h` file which I want to specify when invoking the compiler. What I do in that .h file is `#undef` some macro and re-define the macro the way I want them to be.

Note: I am aware of `--preinclude` option in gcc, but using `--preinclude` over-rides my extra.h by the .h of the original source code. What I need is some kind of post include option.

Comment: I donot know why one line became big font and bold. I apologize if you find that annoying.

Comment: Why can't you change the source code?  Is this related to a homework assignment?

Comment: No, this is not my homework. I need to wrap certain macro calls and gather and do some pre and post processing. The reason I cannot change the source code is that customers would want to have their code touched.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Why can't I? Because [the source code](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xorgxrdp/blob/150c0b2eb7bf470939d97baae24af192758cfa7a/module/rdpClientCon.c#L2606-L2607) is not mine and is out of my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you uniformly have one specific header that is always included last in the source files, this is going to be tricky.

I think the way I'd approach it, if I had to, would be:

- Create a new directory, call it `headers`.
- Put in there suitable dummy headers with the same name as the regular headers, which would contain `#include "extra.h"` at the end (or possibly `#include <extra.h>`, but I would try to avoid that).
- The dummy headers would also include the original files by some mechanism, possibly even using `#include "/usr/include/header.h"` but preferably some other technique - such as `#include "include/header."`.
- The `extra.h` header would always redefine all its macros - it would not have the normal `#ifndef EXTRA_H_INCLUDED` / `#define EXTRA_H_INCLUDED` / `#endif` multiple inclusion guards, so that each time it is included, it would redefine the relevant macros.
- Consequently, `extra.h` cannot define any types.  (Or, more precisely, if it does, those must be protected against multiple definition by multiple include guards; the key point is that the macros must be defined each time the file is included - a bit like `<assert.h>`.)
- Each redefined macro would be explicitly protected by `#undef REDEFINED_MACRO` and then `#define REDEFINED_MACRO ...`.
- There is no point in testing whether the macro is defined before undefining it.
- The build process would be modified to look in the `headers` directory before looking anywhere else.  The compiler option would be `-I./headers` or something similar, depending on exactly where you locate the `headers` directory.
- Depending on how you have decided to locate the normal versions of the headers, you might need another `-I` option (such as `-I/usr` if you've used `#include "include/header.h"` notation) to locate the standard headers again.

The upshot is that your private headers get used directly by the compiler, but they include the standard headers and then your `extra.h` header - thus achieving what you wanted without modifying the C source or the normal headers.

But there is something misguided about the whole attempt...you would be better off not trying this.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there are multiple places where the header files are kept. I am working with kernel source code, and then there are custom kernel modules. It is just wrong to do a # include of all the header files in extra.h. Though I just have one uniform header file and I want to use it at the end of all include files.

Comment: @user420536: as I hinted, this is totally gruesome, and not dreadfully reliable, but then the concept of 'last included header' is unreliable and not clearly defined.  Why do you think you need to rewrite kernel macros?  That sounds like a recipe for total disaster.  The kernel defines what it expects.  If you redefine what it expects to match what you expect, it will win - by crashing in your code when you confuse it.  Use your own macros for your purposes; leave the kernel macros strictly alone.  **DO NOT LIE TO YOUR COMPILER OR KERNEL**

Comment: The reason I need to redefine kernel macros is to tap some kernel calls and wrap them in my code. But for some reason, I cannot expect the module code to do a #include of my extra.h I do not redefine the kernel macros exactly. You can think like this that I just want to add a debug statement every time a specific macros are invoked, but I am not allowed to change the source code.

Comment: @user420536: I suggest you get whoever is laying the strictures on you about not changing the code to do the work - or explain to you how they expect you to do it.  They are not being reasonable.

Comment: @Jonathan, I cannot ask the customers to do the work :). I am just trying to work around limitations. Simply put what I want is that my definitions to macros be final definitions. If I do a pre-include, my definitions get over-ridden by actual definitions. If there was a pre-processor macro like #ignore-redifine, I would have got my way out. I agree there is no concept last include.

Comment: @user420536: why are the customers insisting you get the code working without making any changes to the code?  I'm out of here; I recommend you get out too, while the going is good.  You can't win until the rules are changed.  They don't have to be changed much, but they do have to be changed.  Besides, you can always make a copy of the code and edit the copy.  If you can't do even that, it is beyond time to get out of town.

Comment: There are a lot of profiling software, that taps into the code but doesn't modify your code. Valgrind is one, they track everytime you do a malloc or free. Would you want to change your code for valgrind. The reason I am stuck is, tapping function calls is not difficult, it can be done at runtime. There are certain macros is kernel that get expanded into different function depending on the configuration parameters. I cannot tap each different function, so I have to intervene the macro itself.

Comment: @user420536: so, if the source code says: `some_macro(arg1, arg2)`, modify it to say `SOME_MACRO(arg1, arg2)` and then write `SOME_MACRO` in your `extra.h` header to do what you want and then use `some_macro()` from the kernel and then do whatever cleanup you want.  It may be a temporary measure - while you're resolving whatever problem you've got - or it could be a permanent fixture.  But if you are compiling the code, you can edit it and fix the problem in the short term.  And use a VCS to keep track of what you're doing.

Comment: @Jonathan, that is how I have got it working. And now I am looking for ways in which I do not need to change some_macro to rather some macro. Rather the situation is

Comment: #define some_macro(arg) _some_macro(arg) //_some_macro is a function

Comment: And what I need to do is : #define some_macro(arg) do{//pre _some_macro(arg) //post}while(0);

Comment: @user420536: And I am of the opinion that doing what you would like to do is not feasible while you remain within the bounds of the C preprocessor.  If you go hacking off into other preprocessors (M4?) or something - maybe.  But even then, probably not.  You want two different definitions of a single macro available concurrently.  That is not possible, IMNSHO.

Comment: No I just want to do a #undef of original macro, and using my macro instead of original macro. But looks like we have hit a block because we are not working on any feasible solution under the constrains.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
`-include file` option of GCC, because of this feature:

`If multiple -include options are given, the files are included in the order they appear on the command line.`

So as I understand you must include ALL *.h files from the command line,- just keep your "extra.h" the last header in `-include` option list and you should get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is to insert extra.h after all the other .h files in a .c file. So adding it at the end of each .h file will insert it between two .h files included in sequence inside a .c file, which is not the intention.

You can use sed/awk inside makefile(s) to:
    - first create duplicate .c files inserting '#include "extra.h"' after other #include lines inside each of the .c files (it will be tedious/ticky to resole #ifdef blocks inside the .c files)
    - then achieve your target compiling those duplicate .c files
    - finally delete the duplicate .c files

Comment: Thanks everyone. Finally it was not feasible without not touching the code. I ended up putting my extra.h at the end of each header file I wanted to modify. As someone already mentioned, C doesn't have a clear demarcation on the last header file included and macros are not limited to .h files. So it was not possible. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of doing this according to your requirements, and both should be relatively simple, I hope.

The first way does not touch the source code at all, however it requires that each header file you are #undef'ing things from has a header guard.  You can copy and concatenate every header file that you need to "change" things in into one monolithic file, your "extra.h" file.  Then at the end of that file, go ahead and redefine all the macros you need.  Then include this file when you compile.  The header guards will prevent the original headers from being included.  Obviously, there are a number of potential problems with this approach, and it certainly wouldn't work in general.

The second way is a lot cleaner and more reliable, but it requires you to edit the code directly, albeit non-intrusively.  For each header you need to redefine things in, make a copy of that header with an ".orig" suffix or something, then edit the actual header file directly.  After you are all done doing whatever you are doing, then just copy all the ".orig" files back into the actual headers before your customers obtain the code.  I assume your requirements aren't so draconian that you can't change the code even temporarily.

If none of that works, then I doubt you are going to find an effective answer from anybody short of hacking GCC directly and adding a "-postinclude" option yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Makefile could be used to redefine the macros through the -U and -D compiler(gcc) options.  But why redefine them after the originals are evaluated?  I cannot think of a need for such a thing.  Can you tell what are you hoping to achieve through this?

Comment: The `-U` and `-D` options are like pre-include - they are set at the beginning and then the headers are processed, probably ignoring the command-line settings, and especially any `-U` options. I'm not sure I've ever used `-U` seriously.  It only allows you to undo built-in (pre-defined) macros, AFAIK.

Comment: You can think like this that I just want to add a debug statement every time a specific macros are invoked, but I am not allowed to change the source code.

Comment: You could try to get a better understanding of the Linux kernel code base in relation to the underlying platform through the documentation or such sources.  Debugging is to understand some behaviour and investigate the causes of it.  What is that behaviour in which you are interested?